# почему в inteliji idea проект стал красным после git init

Tags: git, intellij-idea

после git init в git bash проект стал красным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это показывает, что файлы не добавлены. Сделайте `git add` или "пкм -> git -> add".

Comment: о боже, спасибо, уже голова вскипела!